# How do you upload a video to youtube using json-c format?

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, youtube

I'm able to upload videos to youtube using their xml input/output format but their documentation on how to implement uploading with json-c is frustratingly sparse.  For instance, what is the 'key' for the json data I'm sticking in the body?  Or put a different way, how is the json string added to the body of the request?

Comment: Have you seen http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/ ? Maybe this will solve your problem. I haven't tried, if and how uploading videos works with this library, but commenting and downloading works beautifully

Comment: What's the reason you want to switch to JSON if the XML format works for you?

Comment: JSON is easily convertible to and from native objects (NSDictionary, NSArray) and its easier (for me) to read inline with Obj-C.  XML on the other hand doesn't translate as well and isn't as easy to parse/create.  Fortunately I can ask youtube to return my result in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Here are instructions for uploading a video using JSON-C:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_jsonc#Add_Video

The upload is done in two parts: 1) First you upload the metadata in JSON format. The response of this will contain an upload url. 2) Upload the actual video to the upload url.

However @Alexander is right, the Objective-C client may be a better route, since it handles all the upload details for you:

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/

Comment: I've read and tried the instructions for hours to no avail, have you actually used them and succeeded?  As far as the gdata client goes, I'm aware that you can upload files using the gdata client and I've  picked their code apart, they don't use JSON-C either so there goes any examples.  I don't want to use their library as its quite bloated and I'm already able to upload files to them using a class I wrote myself that interfaces with the API directly, I just want to do it using JSON-C instead of XML.

Comment: Do you have a snippet of the code that is breaking, and the error message you are receiving?

Comment: Its been a long time since I was trying to get it working but the problem came down to it wasn't able to find or parse the JSON data I was putting in the body and the error message was useless (something to the effect of 'invalid body').  Which made me believe I wasn't providing the JSON in the right format or with the right key or something but trial and error wasn't producing any results and the documentation didn't help.